# Android sms speaker app

Tags: android, sms

I am developing an android app which speaks the sms it receives. Now, it works fine in my friend's android device, but in my device, the app does not speak the sms. Is there any settings that I need to configure in my device?

Comment: Did you check the volume level of your mobile ? It may be possible that your mobile is in mute mode.

Comment: Yah, its the volume level, I feel like a stupid.

Comment: Don't be.... Legends do these kind of small mistakes. Is you application on Market Place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not necessary that it is technical coding problem only. I suggest you to check your mic volume in your phone. I believe your mobile is in silent mode when you are executing the application.

If your phone is in silent mode then it will not at all to execute TTS API, unless you set your mic volume programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure Text to speech setting from accessibility menu in settings.

Comment: I have previously worked with TTS, but never notice such settings.

Comment: There is text to speech setting in my phone.

Comment: @alu, What I am saying is that you dont need to do personalized TTS setting. Otherwise each user who installs the application, you need to guide him/her first to set the TTS setting.